# How to adjust horizontal lines of error bars?

Tags: python, python-3.x, plotly

Here is a code:

```
import plotly.graph_objects as go

fig = go.Figure()
fig.add_trace(go.Bar(
    name='Group 1',
    x=['Var 1', 'Var 2', 'Var 3'], y=[3, 6, 4],
    error_y=dict(type='data', array=[1, 0.5, 1.5]),
    width=0.15
))
fig.add_trace(go.Bar(
    name='Group 2',
    x=['Var 1', 'Var 2', 'Var 3'], y=[4, 7, 3],
    error_y=dict(type='data', array=[0.5, 1, 2]),
    width=0.15
))
fig.update_layout(barmode='group')
fig.show()
```

It works well and produces:

[image]

**Question:** How to change the length of the horizontal lines at the end of of error bars? I mean this ones:

[image]

Comment: Maybe you can find some light on this matter under https://plotly.com/python/reference/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You just need to set the `width` parameter like this:

```
error_y=dict(type='data', array=[0.5, 1, 2], width=20)
```

### Output example

After modifying that line for Group 2 in your code you can get for example:

[image]

### Parameters reference

You can see the reference for parameters under https://plotly.com/python/reference/

Comment: Thank you also for pointing the reference. Sometimes it is not easy to figure out were is what in Plotly documentation.